# urlencoding in pear changes post request values

Tags: php, http, curl, pear

I recently downloaded PEAR package and i'm currently using HTTP_Requst2.
It was working find until i tried posting to a site that included a hidden parameter that had a space in the value: &login=Sign In

The problem is that the HTTP_Request is urlencoding the request so my post is sent as: &login=Sign+In

I tried both adapters(curl & socket) but no luck, I know it's out there but you guys always helped in the pass.

Comment: Are you sure this is not the HTTPD that is urlencoding the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` is how the space char should be encoded. So `HTTP_Request2` behaviour is perfectly valid.

Comment: yes i totally agree... unfortunately i need it to be sent as a space and not plus....when i compare wireshark results from a normal browser and Request the only difference is the login parameter and as a result i'm not getting the cookie....
Thanks a million BTW!!!

Comment: @Danny Valariola: well, it is wrong. Space cannot be passed in a data field as a space